# Unexpected behaviour in linq query with lazy loading on ravendb

Tags: linq, lazy-loading, ravendb

I had a problem with the following code. When I don't call `ToList()` on the initial `RavenSession.Query<Item>()` call, the `PhotoPath` property is null in the `ItemSummaryModel` object. Is this a lazy loading issue or something else that's causing this?

The `PhotoPath` property was null on the initial save of this document. I then updated it in a subsequent edit.

When I query for the full item instead of selecting a new object it works as expected populating all properties.

Why did I have to force query execution with `ToList()` for the new `ItemSummaryModel` to be populated as expected?

```
var fullItems = RavenSession.Query<Item>().ToList();
var items = (from i in fullItems
             where i.DateAdded >= DateTime.Now.Subtract(new TimeSpan(10,0,0,0))
             orderby i.DateAdded
             select new ItemSummaryModel()
             {
                  Id = i.Id,
                  PhotoPath = i.ListingPhotoPath,
                  MarketingInfo = i.MarketingInfoShort,
                  Name = i.Name,
                  Summary = i.Summary,
                  PriceTypeCode = i.ClearancePrice > 0 ? PriceType.Clearance : (i.SalePrice > 0 ? PriceType.Sale : PriceType.List),
                  ListSaleOrClearancePrice = i.ClearancePrice > 0 ? i.ClearancePrice : (i.SalePrice > 0 ? i.SalePrice : i.Price)
             }).Take(nbrOfItems);
return items;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RavenDB's linq provider is pretty simplistic, it can't currently handle field remapping.
In other words, it can't handle it that you did this:

```
                     PhotoPath = i.ListingPhotoPath,
```

If you changed it to

```
                     ListingPhotoPath = i.ListingPhotoPath,
```

It will work.
That is an issue that is scheduled to be fixed